# Al ejecutar StartActivity para recargar la pagina me vuelve a la Anterior

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo a el textView stock al que le añado un  OnClickListener  para cambiar un valor, lo que intento es que cuando le haga click se cambie el valor y se vuelva a cargar la activity para que se muestre el valor cambiado en la activity.

El problema que tengo es que cuando pulso sobre el textView me hace una transición muy rara, se pone en blanco y después vuelve a la activity anterior.

Si lo que hago el Intent me redirija a la anterior directamente lo de la pantalla en blanco no pasa y haca la transición hacia al lado como hace normalmente.

```
stock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MostrarActivy.class);
            i.putExtra("imagenurl", getIntent().getStringExtra("imagenurl"));
            i.putExtra("nombre", getIntent().getStringExtra("nombre"));
            i.putExtra("peso", getIntent().getStringExtra("peso"));
            i.putExtra("precio", getIntent().getStringExtra("precio"));

            String id_String = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
            int id_int = Integer.parseInt(id_String);


            SqlLite admin = new SqlLite(getApplicationContext(), "productos", null,1);
            SQLiteDatabase Basededatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor fila = Basededatos.rawQuery("Select stock From productos Where id =" + id_int, null);

            if (fila.moveToFirst()) {

                String valorStock = fila.getString(0);


                if (valorStock.equals("Si")) {

                    String upStock = "No";

                    ContentValues registros = new ContentValues();
                    registros.put("stock", upStock );

                    int cantidad = Basededatos.update("productos", registros, "id=" + id_int, null );
                    Basededatos.close();

                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();

                } else if (valorStock.equals("No")){

                    String upStock = "Si";

                    ContentValues registros = new ContentValues();
                    registros.put("stock", upStock );

                    int cantidad = Basededatos.update("productos", registros, "id=" + id_int, null );
                    Basededatos.close();

                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();

                }

            }




            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Comment: A ver si lo entiendo. Cada vez que pulsas el TextView quieres lanzar de nuevo la misma activity para que se muestre con el TextView cambiado? No tendría más sentido que solo actualizaras el TextView sin cambiar de Activity?

Comment: Si el `TextView` está en la misma Activity no tienes que recargar la Activity para cambiar su valor, simplemente usa `mTextView.setText("Nuevo texto");`  para actualizarlo, asumiendo que `mTextView` hace referencia el objeto en cuestión.

Comment: Acabo de intentar hacer eso pero sigue haciendo lo mismo, me hace volver a la anterior para poder ver el cambio

Comment: Es que no necesitas `Intent` ni `startActivity` si el `TextView`  está en la misma Activity, simplemente lo puedes modificar con `setText`, pulsa en [edit] y dinos cómo lo estás intentando después de lo que te hemos sugerido.

Comment: Arreglado, había cometido un fallo por el medio